# How to click button when out of focus

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two Windows forms on a Program.

E.g) MainForm, SubForm

SubForm have a focus and I tried click a button on the MainForm but I had to click twice because of out of focus.

I think MainForm get focus when first click and make click event when second click so I want to making click event pass the "Getting Focus" process.

How can I do?

Sorry for bad english describing.

Thank you.

=== add photo for describing ===

[GIF Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooVCO.gif)
[image]

Comment: What does *I tried click a button on the MainForm* imply here? Clicking how? Using your Mouse? That shouldn't happen. What are you trying to do? Describe the sequence of actions explicitly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using the exact scenario you described, so there must be something missing you are not showing us. Please describe in full detail the steps and code that leads to your problem

Comment: Added GIF File.
thank you.

Comment: I think you should redesign your forms. From a UX point of view, each form should have one scope, if two forms are so interactive that they need to be focused at the same time, that’s a strong indicator they should be merged.

Comment: I want to minimize and unminimize just click once but that forms cannot that. That gif is example senario,

Comment: I can't remember whether WinForms that are unfocussed form can react to a mouse over event, which could be used put it into focus, but if not you could have a sub-process that tracks the mouse pointer in relation for form boundaries and put it in focus.